# "Please select a keyboard layout" notification on wake?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notifications, external-keyboard

I have an RCA brand tablet that came with its own physical keyboard.  Whenever I connect this keyboard or turn on the screen while the keyboard is connected, I get this notification:
[image: The Notification]

If I click on the notification, I am brought here:
[image: The Destination]

So, the notification doesn't take me anywhere where I can select a keyboard layout.  I've tried to go into the individual settings for each keyboard and found an option to select a layout, but if I click on that option, it sends me right back to `Screenshot 2`.  Therefore I can't select a keyboard layout and I can't get rid of the notification.  It is incredibly frustrating to have to keep clearing out the same notification over and over.  How can I stop the notification?

Note that it does the same thing if I am using the AOSP keyboard instead of the SwiftKey keyboard.  I am running android 4.4.2.